# How to display 4 quadrants on Cartesian graph? mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, cartesian

How can I get Mathematica to display all 4 quadrants, not just the area where my data exists. I'm building an application to illustrate how matrix transformations affect a graphed shape and I want all 4 quadrants displayed for every step. I tried PlotRange, but it throws an error.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[B.A], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange{{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

Comment: As an option, `PlotRange` needs to be specified as a `Rule` (i.e., with an arrow).

Comment: `PlotRange {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}` is interpreted as multiplication of the symbol `PlotRange` and the list `{{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}`. Which is `{{-10 PlotRange, 10 PlotRange}, {-10 PlotRange, 10 PlotRange}}`. See the Options section of `ListPlot` [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html).